# Test case for finding the height of a binary tree

Tags: ocaml

I'm wrote a function that finds the height of a binary tree (i.e. the # of nodes along the longest path from the root to the leaf).

```
let rec height (t: 'a tree) : int =
begin match t with
| Empty -> 0
| Node (l, v, r) -> 1 + max (height 1) (height r)
end
```

I believe that my function is correct, but the syntax error that occurs when I run my test says "this function is applied to too many arguments; maybe you forgot a ';'.

This is my test case

```
let test () : bool =
height Node(Node(Empty, 1, Empty), 3, Node(Empty, 2, Node(Empty, 4, Empty))) = 3
;; run_test "Node(Node(Empty, 1, Empty), 3, Node(Empty, 2, Node(Empty, 4, Empty)))" test
```

What is wrong with my test case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the expression

```
height Node (Empty, 0, Empty)
```

In OCaml, adjacent values indicate function application, which is left-associative. So this is the same as:

```
(height Node) (Empty, 0, Empty)
```

The following will work:

```
height (Node (Empty, 0, Empty))
```

In other words, you just need to add parentheses.